# Form filed validation value returning empty

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am setting up a form with a few fields and I want to validate before submit, I am just checking that the input fields are not empty my issue is that my script is bypassing the if test and is going straight in to the else function.

```
<div id="personalInfo" class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
<div class="acc_info_q"> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#personal_info"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Personal Information</a> 
  <span id="stats2" class="fieldStatus pull-right">
    <i class="fa"></i> &nbsp;</span></div>

    <div id="personal_info"> 
      <div class="col-sm-6 control-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address">
        </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 control-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City">
        </div>  
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <hr>
    <button type="button" value="next" class="next1">Next</button>
  </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of collapsed -->
    </div>
```

this form has 2 fields and on click the script should look at the input fields and check for value, if now value it adds a fa-times class else it adds a fa-check class, them problem is that if skips the if and it goes straight to the else here is the JS code

```js
$('.next1').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).parent().find("input").filter(function() {
    return this.value === "";
  });
  console.log("value.length" +value.length)
  if (value.length) {
    //At least one input is empty
    $('#stats2').find('i').addClass('fa-times');
  } else {
    $('#stats2').find("i").removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-check')
     
   
  }
});
```

here is a codepen I even added a console.log and it it returns 0 when the fields are empty and it should return 2

[codepen](http://codepen.io/dnajar/pen/yJBRmG)

Comment: `value` is not an array, why are you calling `length` on it?

Comment: @MikeBrant, it would be if the selector is correct

Answer (score 0):

You should use `id` selector instead of `.parent()` (which in your case is `.text-center` and has no `input` elements)

```
var value = $('#personal_info').find("input").filter(function() {
    return this.value === "";
});
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick I wasn't looking at it that closely.